# Composition of integer in C and Haskell

Tags: c, haskell

I want to find a [Composition of Integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) in C  and Haskell
I find this code for Haskell which works fine:

```
composition 0 = [[]]
composition n = [x:rest | x <- [1..n], rest <- composition (n-x)]
```

Sample output of this Code Is:

```
*Main> composition 3 
[[1,1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[3]]

*Main> composition 4 
[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,3],[2,1,1],[2,2],[3,1],[4]]
```

but I could not develop an equivalent in C:
I tried to create recursive function in C but I don't know how to use equivalent of Haskell :[] in C

```
void composition(int n)
{
        int j;
        if (n==0)
                return;
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
                printf ("%d",j);
                composition(n-j);
                printf("\n");
        }

}
```

sample Output of this code is:

```
Composition is
111

2

21

3
```

The correct composition for 3 is

```
1 1 1
2 1
1 2
3
```

Comment: your question is a little confusing. What exactly are you asking about? C or C# solution? Can you describe for the people who don't know Haskell what the expression: `generate n = [x:rest | x <- [1..n], rest <- generate (n-x)]` does? The more information you provide the easier will it be for the people to answer your question

Comment: @LuckAss I add C output

Comment: @progy_rock 1) I know but I don't know how to fix it 2) I didn't develop it yet, anyway I also and do not know how to create array in a recursive way like I did in Haskel with : colon.

Comment: @progy_rock there is sample C# code on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048329/finding-all-numbers-that-sum-to-a-specified-target-number-integer-partition but I want a recursive one

Comment: @progy_rock ok I delete the C# section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using printf is not really equivalent : it outputs the result to stdout instead of returning it as list object. In C++ you could do

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > composition(int n)
{
    int j;
    if (n == 0)
        return std::vector<std::vector<int> >(0);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > ret;
    ret.push_back(std::vector<int>(1, n));
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) 
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<int> > rec = composition(n - j);
        for (auto& it : rec)
            it.push_back(j);
        ret.insert(ret.begin(), rec.begin(), rec.end());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Now if you really want plain C, you have to dynamically allocate the vectors yourself. It is not very fun.

Comment: What If I don't want a list just print on a screen, something like this sudo code: foreach y in composition(n-j) {printf ( j,y) } which y is probably a list

Comment: Compute the list first, then print it.