# Generate numeric partitions for integer

Tags: r, statistics, package, partition

Is there any implementation of [integer partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) in R?

For example for input 4 I would like to get 5 vectors:

```
4
3 , 1
2 , 2
2 , 1 , 1
1 , 1 , 1 , 1
```

There are implementations in [Python, Erlang, Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400794/generating-the-partitions-of-a-number), [C](http://www.programminglogic.com/integer-partition-algorithm/), [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/Integer-Partition-0.05/Partition.pm), but I can't find anything in R.

Comment: `library("sos"); findFn("partitions")` finds a few too many hits, but the third package listed is the `partitions` package referred to by @AnandaMahto ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "partitions" package:

```
install.packages("partitions")
library(partitions)
parts(4)
#               
# [1,] 4 3 2 2 1
# [2,] 0 1 2 1 1
# [3,] 0 0 0 1 1
# [4,] 0 0 0 0 1
```