# How would I loop through an array and find any combination of numbers that adds up to equal a target number?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have thought about this issue a lot, and I have found a way to do it, but there has to be a better way. I want to enter a target number, then loop through an array and find any possible combination of numbers that adds up to equal that target number.

For example, I know this code works to find all combinations of two numbers that add up to equal the target number:

```
For i as Integer = 0 To MyArray.Length - 1
    For j as Integer = (i + 1) To MyArray.Length - 1
        If(MyArray(i) + MyArray(j)) = TargetNumber Then
            'Output these two numbers
        EndIf
    Next
Next
```

As you can see, this algorithm is designed only to get combinations of two numbers that add up to equal the target number. I know that I could nest another `For` loop (or as many as I want) to find as many numbers as I want to find, but there has to be a better, more efficient way. I don't want to have to nest another loop every time I want to find another number. Any suggestions? Should I avoid using arrays and try some other approach? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try using recursive function.

Comment: @J3soon I'll be honest, recursion isn't my greatest skill. Could you post a suggestion?

Comment: if MyArray is `{1, 2}`, and input number is `3`, do you want to show the `1, 1, 1` combination?

Comment: No that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: If MyArray is {1,2,3,4,5} and TargetNumber = 10, the algorithm should output: (5+4+1), (1+2+3+4), (5+2+3) etc.

Comment: You are looking for [Partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29). Already solved [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400794/generating-the-partitions-of-a-number)

Comment: @AlexB. Thanks for the link. I don't exactly want partitions. Partitions express every possible combination of numbers that are less than or equal to the target number. I want those numbers to come from a predefined list, or array in this case. I have no need to know any combinations of numbers that do not involve numbers in the array.

Comment: Yes I know, but you could start with a partition and restrict it to your needs. I guess it will not be a huge problem to e.g. exclude certain values which are not in your array.

Comment: So the most straightforward and easy way is by using recursive, when `MyArray` doesn't contains many numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wont repeat any number in the `BasicNums` array, and it means that only specified number can print out the number combination.

Code below:

```
Module Module1

    Dim BasicNums() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
    Dim nums As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim TargetNumber As Integer

    Sub Main()
        TargetNumber = Console.ReadLine()
        Recursion(0, 0, 0)  'start recursive
        Console.ReadLine()  'pause the console
    End Sub

    Sub Recursion(ByVal depth As Integer, ByVal start As Integer, ByVal count As Integer)
        'depth -> the recursion's depth (the 'for' count)
        'start -> where the next for starts
        'count -> current number count
        If count = TargetNumber Then
            'when [count] equals [TargetNumber] print the combination nums
            For j As Integer = 0 To nums.Count - 1
                Console.Write(nums(j) & " ")
            Next
            Console.Write(vbCrLf)
            Return
        ElseIf depth = BasicNums.Length - 1 Then
            'stop the recursion when the recursion meets the length of [BasicNums]
            Return
        End If
        For i As Integer = start To BasicNums.Length - 1
            nums.Add(BasicNums(i))
            Recursion(depth + 1, i + 1, count + BasicNums(i))
            nums.Remove(BasicNums(i))
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Example Input:

```
7
```

Output:

```
1 2 4
1 6
2 5
3 4
7
```

Comment: It appears that this will work. Could you explain your parameters for the `Recursive` function?

Comment: @J3son your solution grows exponentially which should be ok for the owners example of 10 numbers.

Comment: I've added some comments

Comment: @AlexB.Yes, so the `Basicnums` length shouldn't be too long.

Comment: @J3soon Thank you! This solution will prevent me from having to write a bunch of nested `For` loops, at least. If there is anyway that this function could be improved, please let me know. I think it is efficient enough to work in most cases, but I foresee some cases that will have many more numbers to try to add together.

Comment: @ic3man7019 It seems that you had unaccepted this answer. Is there any wrong parts in my answer?