# print the out put of python program based on Permituation and combination

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I write a program in python to find no of combinations of series

there is one dice which has 6 faces.

user input 2

then the out is shown is as no of count where two is come in combinations

ex if we throw dice for to get 2 as sum the maximum are two dice thrown are required

```
(1+1) and (2) so count is 2
```

if i throw for sum of 3, the out-put is

```
(1+1+1),(1+2),(2+1),(3) so count is 4 enter code here
```

if i throw for sum of 4 then the out put is

```
(1+1+1+1),(1+1+2),(1+2+1),(2+1+1),(2+2),(3+1),(1+3),(4) count is 8
```

I write the code is

```
# I am considering the Board is horizontal single line

def count_values(values,num):
    for i in range(num):
        print(values[i]," ",end='')
    print('')

def print_list(out_put,values,num,count=0,show=False):
    dice=6
    if num == 0:
        count_values(values,count) 
        out_put[0] += 1
    elif num > 0:
        for k in range(1,dice+1):
            values[count] = k
            print_list(out_put,values,num-k, count+1,show)

n=int(input('Enter A number'))

values=[0]*n
out_put=[0]
print_list(out_put,values,n)
print(out_put)
```

it shows out put for small inputs likes 10,20,30
but
i want the out put for 100 and 500 and 610 like inputs ,
but is get more time (around 5-6 hours still running) and the count of combination is more than 1145201564
still it is counting
any one has solution for this

Any one has any solution. for this

Comment: It looks like you're counting [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). If you need to generate them as well, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400794/generating-the-partitions-of-a-number)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. but i got a solution by using numpy library, it give out put very fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy

def findway(m,n,x):
    table = numpy.zeros((2,x+1))
    for j in range(1,x+1):
            table[1][j] = 1

    for j in range(1,x+1):
            for k in range(1,j):
                    table[1,j] += table[1][j-k]

    print table[1][x]

n=input('Enter a number')
findway(6,1,n)
```

but here is also one problem, i want out put for 600 ,but it shows out-put in format (2.07475778444e+180)
but i want in integer format